# Program failing for huge input file, works perfectly for smaller input files

Tags: c++, openstreetmap, adjacency-list

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{


    ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open("C:\\Users\\Sean\\Desktop\\test.txt", ios::in);

    string line;
    getline(inFile, line);
    std::istringstream lstream(line);
    int n,m;
    stringstream ss(line);
    ss >> n >> m;


    cout << "n=" << n << " m= " << m << endl;


    vector<int> adj[n];



    //cout << "got here" << endl;


    int j = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int largest = 0;
    int total = 0;





    while (getline(inFile, line))
    {



    std::istringstream lstream(line);
    //cout << line << endl;
    int val;

    while (lstream>> val)
    {


    addEdge(adj, i, val);
    j++;
    total++;

    }

    if(j>largest){ largest = j;}
    j = 0;
    i++;

    }

    cout << "Largest =" << largest << endl;
    cout << "Average =" << (float)total/n << endl;
```

So this program is reading in graphs from Open Street Map. n and m are the first two ints in the file, for number for vertices and number of edges.

As in the title, program works perfectly for smaller "play" files but shuts down it seems at trying to declare a vector of ints of in this case 463514 size.

Any help appreciated. Bit lost here.

This is what addEdge is upto:

```
void addEdge(vector<int> adj[], int u, int v)
{
    adj[u].push_back(v);

};
```

Comment: `vector<int> adj[n];` creates an array of `n`  vectors, but since it's a [variable-length array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) it's not really valid C+, because C++ doesn't have those. If you want an "array" whose size is set at run-time use `std::vector` (as in `std::vector<std::vector<int>> adj(n);`) Not that it matters since your code doesn't really use it  or the data you add to it.

Comment: As a possible ***guess*** about your problem, I would say it's a *stack overflow*. Local variables, including VLA's (on compiler which add that as an extension), are put on the *stack*. The stack is a limited resource, on Windows the default process stack is only a single MiB, on e.g. Linux it's typically 8 MiB. Your array is simply to large to fit on the stack is my guess. That will be solved by stop using non-portable extensions and use the standard vector instead (where the main memory will be the limit instead).

Comment: Don't try to reinvent the wheel. Use [libosmium](https://osmcode.org/libosmium/) for reading OSM files. Also, `std::vector` is the wrong container for storing coordinates as index since it is essentially an array. It will allocate an enormous amount of memory when adding large numbers.